# How to change shipping method title dynamically in magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I have created one **custom shipping method**, I need to change shipping method title dynamically.

public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->isActive())
        {
            return false;
        }

```
    $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

    $shippingPrice = 15;//$this->getConfigData('price'); //this is updating price at run time

    $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

    $method->setCarrier($this->getCarrierCode());
    $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

    $method->setMethod($this->getCarrierCode());
    $method->setMethodTitle("custom title");//($this->getConfigData('name')); this is not working

    $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
    $method->setCost($shippingPrice);

    $result->append($method);
    return $result;
}
```

But its not working.

Comment: Show your code that you tried

Comment: please post your carrier code

Comment: @magefms , please check I updated my question.

Comment: try to set your `$method->setMethod('static code of your shipping method');` and check

Comment: the static code I am talking here is the group id of your custom shipping method defined in config.xml and system.xml in admin

Comment: Below code is working fine for me  

$test = 'test1';
$test2 = 'test2';
$method->setCarrier($this->getCarrierCode());
$method->setCarrierTitle($test2); 
$method->setMethod($this->getCarrierCode());
$method->setMethodTitle($test);